# Confidence ellipse formula in JS or R

Tags: r, ggplot2, ellipse, confidence-interval

**What I have**: A scatter chart(plot) of PCA. Plotted in JS. I have Rtools that Ive used to push PCA data to the client side.

**What I'm trying to do**: Plot a confidence ellipse formula.

I can't seem to find a straight forward formula for the CI ellipse. I came across a lot of theory and a lot of examples in R which give you the end result - an ellipse (One can use ggplot or CRAN to plot it). 
But Im looking for a formula that I could use in the client side to plug my scatter chart points and calculate the ellipse or even better a function in R that would give me a formula for the ellipse.
I have the covariance matrix and Eigen vectors as well (calculated in R).

All suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: what about `library(ggbiplot)` I don't know how to extract the ellipse formula (although I'm sure you can), but it produces nice ggplots with elispes drawn out out of the box

Comment: @NathanDay thanks for your suggestion, but as I mentioned these libraries will give me the end result and Im looking for the logic/formula used to get the end result. Thanks

Comment: If you want the _theory_ behind the graphics, you might be better off asking on CrossValidated. Note that the theory is independent of the implementation, ie you'll get a mathematical formula -- but that's what you're asking for.

Comment: @HongOoi Thanks, Ill have a look at CrossValidated. And you're right one of things Im asking for is a mathematical formula, but I'm also looking for a suggestion maybe there is a way to get the logic used to calculate the ellipse from R. Thanks

Comment: I plot them using `Momocs:::conf_ell`

Comment: `car::ellipse` is a standard implementation. I think that is also what `ggplot` uses in `stat_ellipse`.

Comment: You can also try looking at the source code. ggbiplot is avalible on github. https://github.com/vqv/ggbiplot/blob/master/R/ggbiplot.r The part you are looking for starts on line 189 I think. You will have to follow up on some of the other functions in there, but figuring out the puzzle is a great way to improve your understanding of R and statistics.

Comment: @Bishops_Guest absolutely, I'll definitely look into that. Some good things came out looking at Monica library ( suggested by VincentBonhomme ). But I'm slightly confused now which ellipse I need ( and it's totally down to me not knowing ), I though in this example https://www.google.co.uk/amp/s/www.r-bloggers.com/computing-and-visualizing-pca-in-r/amp/?client=safari the ellipses created by GG plot are called confidence ellipses, but someone pointed out that they might be "error margin" ellipse

Comment: @NeilVarnas the source code for yet another R implementation is [here](https://github.com/drammock/phonR/blob/master/R/phonR.R#L1362-L1384)

Answer (score 0):

Haven't found a formula but after using **Momocs:::conf_ell** [library](http://vbonhomme.github.io/Momocsdoc/conf_ell.html) I managed to get the vertices and the x,y points of an ellipse.
I will update this answer once I find the second part to my answer - a straight forward formula.